# What are the factor on which PID_MAX depends in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

I have checked two linux systems, both were of 64 bit but PID_MAX is different for both of them.

**On one system(SYSTEM1)**

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
32768
```

**SYSTEM1 configuration:**

> dmesg | grep -i smp.*allow

```
getconf PAGESIZE
4096

cat /proc/cpuinfo | awk '/^processor/{print $3}' | tail -1
11
cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 45
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2430 0 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 1803
cpu MHz     : 2201.000
cache size  : 15360 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 6
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 4389.48
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 45
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2430 0 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 1803
cpu MHz     : 2201.000
cache size  : 15360 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 6
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 4389.48
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 45
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2430 0 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 1803
cpu MHz     : 2201.000
cache size  : 15360 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 6
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 4
initial apicid  : 4
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 4389.48
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 45
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2430 0 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 1803
cpu MHz     : 1300.000
cache size  : 15360 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 6
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 6
initial apicid  : 6
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 4389.48
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 4
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 45
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2430 0 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 1803
cpu MHz     : 2201.000
cache size  : 15360 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 6
core id     : 4
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 8
initial apicid  : 8
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 4389.48
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 5
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 45
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2430 0 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 1803
cpu MHz     : 1200.000
cache size  : 15360 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 6
core id     : 5
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 10
initial apicid  : 10
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 4389.48
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 6
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 45
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2430 0 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 1803
cpu MHz     : 2201.000
cache size  : 15360 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 6
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 32
initial apicid  : 32
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 4392.34
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 7
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 45
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2430 0 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 1803
cpu MHz     : 2201.000
cache size  : 15360 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 6
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 34
initial apicid  : 34
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 4392.34
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 8
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 45
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2430 0 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 1803
cpu MHz     : 2201.000
cache size  : 15360 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 6
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 36
initial apicid  : 36
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 4392.34
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 9
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 45
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2430 0 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 1803
cpu MHz     : 2201.000
cache size  : 15360 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 6
core id     : 3
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 38
initial apicid  : 38
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 4392.34
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 10
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 45
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2430 0 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 1803
cpu MHz     : 1200.000
cache size  : 15360 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 6
core id     : 4
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 40
initial apicid  : 40
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 4392.34
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 11
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 45
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2430 0 @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 1803
cpu MHz     : 1200.000
cache size  : 15360 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 6
core id     : 5
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 42
initial apicid  : 42
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 4392.34
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

**Whereas on other(SYSTEM2), it was**

```
 cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
65536
```

**SYSTEM2 configuration:**

> dmesg | grep -i smp.*allow
>
> SMP: Allowing 64 CPUs, 61 hotplug CPUs

```
getconf PAGESIZE
4096

cat /proc/cpuinfo | awk '/^processor/{print $3}' | tail -1
2

cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 23
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5450  @ 3.00GHz
stepping    : 6
microcode   : 4294967295
cpu MHz     : 2992.467
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 3
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 3
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc rep_good unfair_spinlock pni ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 hypervisor lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5984.93
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 38 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 23
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5450  @ 3.00GHz
stepping    : 6
microcode   : 4294967295
cpu MHz     : 2992.467
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 3
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 3
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc rep_good unfair_spinlock pni ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 hypervisor lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5984.93
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 38 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 23
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5450  @ 3.00GHz
stepping    : 6
microcode   : 4294967295
cpu MHz     : 2992.467
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 3
core id     : 2
cpu cores   : 3
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc rep_good unfair_spinlock pni ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 hypervisor lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5984.93
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 38 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

From man pages.

> proc/sys/kernel/pid_max     This file (new in Linux 2.5) specifies the
> value at which PIDs wrap around   (i.e., the value in this file is one
> greater than the maximum PID). The   default value for this file,
> 32768, results in the same range of PIDs as   on earlier kernels. On
> 32-bit platfroms, 32768 is the maximum value for   pid_max. On 64-bit
> systems, pid_max can be set to any value up to 2^22   (PID_MAX_LIMIT,
> approximately 4 million).

Please note, both of these system were having same linux kernel but SYSTEM2 was running on hyper-V.

Now, my question is what are factors which are responsible for changing pid_max?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: To answer your question, we need to know more data about both of your systems. (1) Do your machines support hot-pluggable CPUs? (2) What is PAGE_SIZE for each of your machine? (3) What is CPU number for each of your machine? (4) What is the value of `CONFIG_BASE_SMALL` in your `/boot/config*` for each of your machine?

Comment: I can provide this information but I just want to know the factors which can change pid_max value.

Comment: Those are: page size of your system and CPU count (current or possible, depending on whether your system allows CPU hot-plugging or not). Still, if you give me your params (mentioned in my previous comment), I can provide more specific answer.

Comment: Ok Sam. I will update this information. Thanks for your efforts

Comment: @sam. I have updated the question. Please check and let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

pid_max is set based on the number of possible CPUs, which you can see in the kernel source in [pid.c line 595](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.7.10/source/kernel/pid.c#L595)

```
pid_max = min(pid_max_max, max_t(int, pid_max,
           PIDS_PER_CPU_DEFAULT * num_possible_cpus()));
```

`num_possible_cpus()` returns the maximum number of CPUs that could be in the system (including hotplug CPUs that could be plugged in after boot).

As you can see the expression includes a minimum and maximum.

The minimum is the initial value of pid_max, which is derived from the macro PID_MAX_DEFAULT, which will be either 0x1000 or 0x8000 depending on the compile-time configuration setting CONFIG_BASE_SMALL.

The maximum is `pid_max_max`, which in turn is derived from some kernel compile-time configuration settings, specifically CONFIG_BASE_SMALL and PAGE_SIZE. This is defined in the macro PID_MAX_LIMIT [see threads.h line 33](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.7.10/source/include/linux/threads.h#L33):

```
#define PID_MAX_LIMIT (CONFIG_BASE_SMALL ? PAGE_SIZE * 8 : \
    (sizeof(long) > 4 ? 4 * 1024 * 1024 : PID_MAX_DEFAULT))
```

So putting all this together in an example: on my system here (Centos 6):

- PAGESIZE is 4096
- CONFIG_BASE_SMALL is 0
- PID_MAX_DEFAULT would therefore be 0x8000 (32768)
- PID_MAX_LIMIT would be 4 * 1024 * 1024 = 4194304
- `max_pid` would therefore be in the range `4194304 >= max_pid >= 32768`

From userland, you can inspect the number of possible CPUs in file `/sys/devices/system/cpu/possible`. The format of the data in this file is a little strange - it will be a string of the form `0-max`, for example `0-15` would mean a maximum of 16 CPUs (noting that the number is zero counting).

For more information about this file and the other files in this directory, see [cputopology.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cputopology.txt).

For more information about CPU hotplugging in general, see  [cpu-hotplug.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-hotplug.txt)

If you want to check the kernel compile time configuration settings, check [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/287372/154273) for some tips.

NB. Kernel line numbers given are valid for Kernel 4.7.10.

Comment: Thanks very much for this information. Could you please let me know how to get the number of possible CPUs in any system?Is there any command /configuration for this?

Comment: @SACHINGOYAL answer has been updated with a little more info showing how to see the num. possible CPUs

Comment: For a 64 bit kernel, in system1, /sys/devices/system/cpu/possible = 0-23.so "PIDS_PER_CPU_DEFAULT * num_possible_cpus()" = 1024*24 = 24576. How come pid_max is 32768 instead of 24576? Please let me know if I overlook anything.

Comment: @SACHINGOYAL as you can see from the expression, there is a minimum value set (pid_max_max). I've added some more comments about how that is derived.